# Using xargs with git

Tags: bash, shell-script, git, xargs

I am trying to practice using `xargs`. I tried the following, passing the SHA1 via `xargs`:

```
$ git show SHA1 --name-only
```

I also tried:

```
$ git log --author=jim --grep="patch" |head -n 1|cut -d ' ' -f2|xargs {} git show {} --name-only
```

It returned `xargs: {}: No such file or directory`

So, I moved on to this:

```
$ git log --author=jim --grep="patch" |head -n 1|cut -d ' ' -f2|xargs -0 -I {} git show {} --name-only
```

Which returned:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'a1237ac27321f2daea365787664e4119b339c483': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

The SHA mentioned is the correct one, but I don't understand why this does not work either

Answer (score 4):

`xargs -0` means to [use only null bytes](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to separate input records, and include newline characters and other whitespace in the input. You're going to have a newline at the end of the revision output there, which `head` and `cut` will leave there, and which will be included in the argument given to `git`. Git doesn't like that. I think you've edited the newline out of the error message, but it is actually a part of the message here and what's causing your problem.

Removing `-0` makes your command work for me. Given the input you're generating, the default newline-separated behaviour of `xargs` is safe.

You don't really need to use `-I {}` in this case either — `git` is quite happy to have the revision as the last argument, but I guess you're using it for practice's sake. By default, `xargs` just puts the arguments at the very end of the given command (unlike `find -exec`, which uses the `{}` substitution).

---

You're also doing a bit much work, though, with your `cut`. Git is more than capable of arranging its output in a format you can use with `xargs`. Using [the `--pretty=tformat...` option](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats) we can make it spit out just the SHA1 hashes, one per line:

```
git log --author=jim --grep="patch" --pretty=tformat:'%H'
```

will output all the hashes of matching commits in your repository, one per line. `--pretty` sets the output formatting; `tformat` means to put a newline at the end of every hash; '%H' means the hash.

You can pipe that into xargs, and since the entire input is "clean" [a-f0-9] you can use it with the default line-separation

Comment: But why doesn't the first version without `-0` and without `-I` work?

Comment: `xargs` doesn't use `{}` for substitution. That's `find`. `xargs` just puts them at the end by default, unless you use `-I`.

Answer (score 0):

- I created git tag for each merge with pipe and with `xargs`:

  - `git log --oneline --merges --pretty=format:"V%ad %H" --date=format:"%Y%m%d_%H_%M" |xargs -n2  git tag --force`

OR

- I created git tag for each merge with pipe and with `awk` in the place of `xargs`:

  - `git log --oneline --merges --pretty=format:"V%ad %H" --date=format:"%Y%m%d_%H_%M" |  awk '{system("git tag --force " $1 " " $2)}'`

OR

- with xargs and bash

  - `git log --oneline --merges --pretty=format:"V%ad %H" --date=format:"%Y%m%d_%H_%M" |   xargs -l bash -c 'git tag $0 $1 --force'`

OR

- An Other with subject in the tag name

  - `git log --oneline --merges --pretty=format:"V%ad_%f %H" --date=format:"%Y%m%d_%H_%M" | sed "s/\./_/g" |   xargs  -l  bash -c 'var="$0" && git tag --force  ${var:0:100} $1'`

and after : `git push --tags origin mytargetbranch`

Infos

- about `xargs` : `-n2` for max args
- https://superuser.com/questions/375690/how-can-i-use-two-parameters-at-once-with-xargs
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770432/xargs-with-multiple-arguments
- to remove all local tags : `git tag | xargs git tag -d`
- to remove all **remote** tags : `git ls-remote --tags origin | sed 's/refs\/tags\///' | sed 's#\^{}##'| cut -f 2 |uniq| xargs git push --delete origin`

Alternative from `git log --oneline --merges --pretty=format:"V%ad_%f %H"`  where  `%f` (sanitized subject) is replaced by `%s` and the perl sanitize to accept extended latin alphabet

```
git log --oneline --merges --pretty=format:"V%ad_%s+++%H" --date=format:"%Y%m%d_%H_%M"| perl -pe 's/[\?\[\]\/\\=<>:;,\x27"&\$#*()|~`!{}%]//g;' |   sed "s/[ .]/_/g" |   sed "s/+++/ /g"  |   sed "s/+//g" | xargs  -l bash -c 'var="$0";git tag --force  ${var:0:100} $1' && git push --tags origin mytargetbranch
```

Infos

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511508/bash-sanitize-file-name-function/43517547#43517547
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700565/how-do-i-escape-single-quotes-with-perl-interpreter/16700890#16700890